# What would be a better database structure for this?

Tags: database, performance, data-structures

I'm building a huge database of IP addresses with their geographic location attached (country, city, ect).

Right now, I'm using this simple database structure:

```
id || ip_addr || country || city ||
```

I've already starting building it, and I've got almost 1 million records, already. The thing is, lots of addresses have the same country attached and fetching from the database is becoming really slow.

I was thinking, if I do this:

**countryTable**:

```
countryID || countryName ||
```

**cityTable**:

```
cityID || cityName || countryID (for what country the city is in) ||
```

and then, **ipTable**:

```
id || ip_addr || countryID || cityID
```

Would it make fetching any faster?

Is this method more efficient (does it have any other benefits)? Or should I just stick to what I have already?

Comment: Yes, this is called normalization. You should go for this new design. Add Foreign Key constraints, too, to preserve integrity at the db level.

Comment: I wouldn't use a relational database for that at all. It maps much more naturally to a trie structure - IP addresses are afterall not assigned randomly, but in in blocks with a common prefix.

Comment: @harold: I like your idea of breaking the IP address to it's 4 parts (as shorts or even bytes). It might even be more efficient in saving space and performance. At the end of the day, it really depends on what you plan to do with the data, once you have it stored. How much are you going to access it? Will you be retrieving entries according to the IP address, the city or the country? etc, etc. All these should affect the way you design the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, moving countries and cities to a separate table is actually a normalization and is a very good step. I would go even further with normalization: a city is located in a country, which means knowing a city you also always know the country. Thus try this:

```
id || ip_addr || cityID
```

**cityTable:**

```
id || cityName || countryID
```

**countryTable:**

```
countryID || countryName
```

An extra reference to the country in IP table is unnecessary. Note that this design is not problematic when several cities have the same name like [Warsaw (Poland)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw), [Warsaw (Indiana, US)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw,_Indiana) and a [dozen others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw_%28disambiguation%29) - there are duplicated names in the database but ids are different - and you identify cities by id - happening to point to the same name (but in different country).

However I don't understand why you have a separate `id` column when unique `ip_addr` exists (providing that a single IP has only one address attached)?

```
ip_addr (ID) || cityID
```

Remember that IP address can and should be represented as a number (some databases have built-in database for that), so such a key is as good as artificial one.

Finally, typically continuous ranges of IPs are assigned to the same area/city/district. You will save a lot of space by assigning a range of IPs to location rather than each and every IP.

Comment: *"An extra reference to the country in IP table is unnecessary." Correct. But you may have more efficient queries that way. Finding all IPs that have `country='US'` will need one join only, not two.

Comment: Awesome answer! But I've come across a few cities that have the same name (also spelled the same way) but are in different countries so I don't think your first suggestion would work. Made a good point about the extra `id` in the ipTable. I'll remove it. Thanks!

Comment: @navnav: It would work fine in those cases. You'll have 2 rows with same `cityName` but different `cityID` (and same or different `countryID`).

Comment: @ypercube: you are right - this is the place where we choose between normalization and performance

Comment: @navnav: no, duplicated city names aren't a problem, I added few words about this to my answer.

Comment: ah! Didn't read the post properly. Sorry. I'll begin changing things now then. Thanks again xD

Answer (score 0):

Yes, normalization typically improves performance. Although the primary reason for normalization is usually data consistency. However in some cases denormalization actually improves performance. This is done in data warehouses and reporting to reduce the number of joins required to filter and compose the result of a query.

One important part here is that the database gets much smaller and more data fits into RAM.

Another key point to performance is having indexes supporting your typical queries.
If you search by city name you should have an index on `cityTable.cityName`, etc. This way the database can find your data using an efficient search, just reading a few records, instead of scanning the whole database.